# Placing the text on background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

How to place the text, on the background image?

```css
.hero {
 background-image: url("../img/photo.jpg");
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="container">
   <p>Welcome to Parallels
Clean Responsive Parallax Theme</p>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Using [CSS positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp) :)

Comment: it's called background-image because it's an image in the background so your text is already on the top of it .. can you be more clear on what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
<figure class="caption">
  <img class="demo" src="https://i.imgur.com/rzReHL0.jpg" alt="Background" />
  <figcaption class="caption-text">This is a caption text</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Is this what you are trying do? this pen should do the job https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMWaXo

```
.caption {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.caption img {
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
 }

 .caption:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%) repeat 0 0;
   z-index: 1;
 }

.caption-text {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    z-index: 5;
 }
```